# How do I validate columns when adding a hive partition?

Tags: hive, parquet

I have a hive table created like this:

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_db.test(
    region STRING,
    start_date STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (
    id STRING
)
STORED AS PARQUET.`

I have a script to add parquet files like this:

`ALTER TABLE test_db.test
ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (
    id = 'abc'
)
LOCATION 's3://location/to/file'`

This script takes user input for the parquet file location. I want to make sure that the parquet file columns match the table columns, but it seems like the ADD PARTITION statement always works, even if the columns are wrong. How can I get hive to validate the columns on ADD?

Answer (score 0):

Hive is `schema-on-read`. When you add the partition with the location of data file, Hive just registers it in its metastore. No schema check is done at this point on the actual data. This is in contrast to traditional relational databases which enforce `schema-on-write`. When the data is actually read, Hive will assign a schema to the underlying data as per the table definition.

**parquet-tools**

For verifying `parquet` file, you can leverage [parquet-tools](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools). This utility can be used to inspect the schema in the `parquet` file. You can include this step in your script, and only add the partition if the `parquet` file schema matches the `Hive` table definition.

Here is an example usage of version 1.6.0:

a. Download JAR:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/twitter/parquet-tools/1.6.0/parquet-tools-1.6.0.jar

b. Inspect schema

```
hadoop jar parquet-tools-1.6.0.jar schema /hdfs/path/to/file.parquet
```